# What is the significance of the current rating of a power source?

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, electromagnetism

Assume, I have a copper coil (solenoid) with exactly 1000 turns. When I connect a multimeter across the 2 ends of the coil, the multimeter gives a resistance value of 20 ohms.

Now I have 2 power sources. One is a 12V and the other is a 3V. If I connect the multimeter to the terminals of these 2 power sources, I get the following readings for current:-

12V = 0.5A current

3V = 2A current.

These are my questions:-

1. **Which of these power sources, when connected to the coil, would result in a stronger electromagnet?**

I am assuming the 12V power source will result in a stronger electromagnet (for same number of turns). My reasoning is:-

I = V/R. R is constant = 20 ohms. So, the current that passes through the coil should be proportional to the voltage across the ends of the coil, which would be equal to voltage of power source.

For 12V, the current through coil = 12V / 20 ohm = 0.6A and for 3V, the current through coil = 3V / 20 ohm = 0.15A

If this is true, my next question is:-

2. **If I = V/R, then what is significance of the current value shown by the multimeter when connected to the terminals of each power source (i.e. 2A for 3V & 0.5A for 12V)? Is it the maximum current that can be drawn from the power source?**

If this second reasoning is correct, then assume the coil's resistance is very low = 0.2 ohms. If we use I = V/R, then the current through the coil for 12V power source should be 12 / 0.2 = 60A. But the maximum current from the 12V power source is 0.5A (based on the multimeter reading)

3. **Then, what will happen in the above scenario? How is the current, voltage, resistance relationship maintained?**

Comment: The current rating of a source has to be above the current requirement of the load. That's it.

Comment: What are your power sources actually? Are they batteries or consumer-grade wall warts, or laboratory-grade benchtop supplies, for example? Add this information to the question rather than answering in comments.

Comment: Your questions range from specific to very broad. Please add details and simplify your questions. VTC if no change.

Comment: If the 20 ohm reading is correct, you cannot get 2A through it from a 3V source. Something is wrong in this story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> One is a 12V and the other is a 3V. If I connect the multimeter to the terminals of these 2 power sources, I get the following readings for current

This is not a good way to measure the current sourcing capabilities of a power supply.

Some sources might be damaged by this test.

Others might have their output current limited by internal resistance.

Others might have a crowbar circuit that changes the mode of operation dramatically when confronted with an excessive conductive load.

Others might have an overcurrent protection circuit that results in an oscillating output voltage (and current) when confronted with an excessively conductive load.

Others might go into a constant current operating mode, which seems to be what you assume is happening.

> Which of these power sources, when connected to the coil, would result in a stronger electromagnet?

If your assumption is right, the 3 V supply should produce only 150 mA through the 20 ohm coil, while the 12 V supply would produce 600 mA, but is limited at 500 mA. So the 12 V supply produces more coil current.

But if you actually measured overcurrent protection behavior or simple internal-resistance limiting when you did your short circuit measurement, then all bets are off.

> If I = V/R, then what is significance of the current value shown by the multimeter when connected to the terminals of each power source?
>
> ...
>
> Is it the maximum current that can be drawn from the power source?
>
> ...
>
> what will happen in the above scenario? How is the current, voltage, resistance relationship maintained?

Without knowing what kind of supply and how it is protected from overcurrent, this can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to the question of which power source will make the stronger electromagnet is: The power source which produces the higher current will create the larger magnetic field thru and around the solenoid. The strength of the magnetic field produced in a coil energized with steady state DC is dependent only on the current passing thru the coil and not the voltage across the coil.

The more complex answer is that the power source may go into a current overload condition as a result of being connected to the 20 Ohm coil. The resulting current will then not be what you expected from your simple Ohm's Law calculation, or from the short circuit test you performed with the ammeter connected directly across the terminals of the power source.

Connect your ammeter in series between the power source (I think you actually mean a "voltage supply".) and the solenoid. The power source which produces the highest current on your ammeter will be the one that produces the higher strength magnetic field (i.e. "stronger electromagnet"). Use the highest amperage range your ammeter offers for both power source tests as this will also impose the lowest resistance into the circuit, thus minimizing the detrimental effect of the ammeter's internal resistance which will "steal" voltage from the coil. This lost voltage will cause your coil to draw slightly less current than it would if the ammeter were not in the circuit - presumably as it will be when you run the coil circuit normally.